# Excel VBA Putting text from a file into a worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

What I want is: To have the data inside the notepad, copied into the worksheet (starting on range A1).

[image: Test]

What I tried:

```
Sub Test()
Dim testfile, textline

testfile = Application.GetOpenFilename()
Open testfile For Input As #1

Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, textline
Loop
Close #1

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = textline
End Sub
```

Result:
[image]

Any advise as to why I am doing wrong, that it won't grab all the text in the notepad, and just the first line? Thanks.

Comment: You are only using range of A1, it's just overwriting it every time.

Comment: Actually, it's only writing to `A1` *once* - it needs to go inside the loop.

Comment: Without coding, you can drag your notepad file onto excel and it will put in all lines.  It should delineate by Tabs automatically, but you can use Data -> Text to Column and specify other parameters.

Comment: @Cyril how would that work? e: I need it to be with a macro, realized it's without coding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there :) . Just need to write every `textline` i separate row, cause now you are changing `Range("A1").Value` only.

```
Sub Test()
Dim testfile, textline

testfile = Application.GetOpenFilename()
Open testfile For Input As #1

i = 1
Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, textline
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value = textline
    i = i + 1
Loop
Close #1

End Sub
```